# arm-linux-androideabi-g++ compile error

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk

I just compile an Android project using Apache ant. Then it reports error:

$ ant debug
Buildfile: C:\Users\xwang\Downloads\MopriaPlugin-Ron\MopriaPlugin-master\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.1
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\xwang\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MopriaPlugin
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

ndk-build:
     [exec] [armeabi] Install        : libwfdsSupport.so => libs/armeabi/libwfdsSupport.so
     [exec] [armeabi] Install        : libwfdsjpeg.so => libs/armeabi/libwfdsjpeg.so
     [exec] [armeabi] Install        : libwfdspng.so => libs/armeabi/libwfdspng.so
     [exec] [armeabi] Install        : libwfdscrypto.so => libs/armeabi/libwfdscrypto.so
     [exec] [armeabi] Install        : libwfdsssl.so => libs/armeabi/libwfdsssl.so
     [exec] [armeabi] Install        : libwfdscups.so => libs/armeabi/libwfdscups.so
     [exec] [armeabi] Compile thumb  : wfds <= google_pdf_renderer_wrapper.c
     [exec] jni/wprint/lib/google_pdf_renderer_wrapper.c: In function 'GooglePDFPageRender':
     [exec] jni/wprint/lib/google_pdf_renderer_wrapper.c:211:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy' [enabled by default]
     [exec]    memcpy(nextRawBufferPosition,(char *)intArrayElements,length);
     [exec]    ^
     [exec] [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libwfds.so
     [exec] arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: C:UsersxwangDownloadsandroid-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a: No such file or directory
     [exec] make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libwfds.so] Error 1

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\xwang\Downloads\MopriaPlugin-Ron\MopriaPlugin-master\ndk_rules.xml:40: exec returned: 2

Total time: 3 seconds

It seems that the compiling environment does not recognize the NDK path. Because it recognized as C:UsersxwangDownloadsandroid-ndk-r10d, which has no separator! Actually, the libgnustl_static.a is at C:\Users\xwang\Downloads\android-ndk-r10d. I have also set up the NDK_HOME environment. Does anybody know how resolve this compile error? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still did not solve this problem.But I just extract the "android-ndk-r10d" folder directly to C disk root directory. So Environment variable is set as NDK_HOME = C:/android-ndk-r10d.

This error does not occur!